# Errors comparing text output from JDBC ResultSet

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, diff, string-comparison

I'm trying to do a word by word comparison of List of Strings that return from two Oracle databases.

I've tried comparing the text using this library ([java-diff-utils](https://github.com/wumpz/java-diff-utils)).

I'm running into inconsistent results when comparing the text output.  [There is a longer description here](https://github.com/wumpz/java-diff-utils/issues/18) of an issue I opened, but it appears that the errors may be a result of the data encoding on the database instead.

I've tried removing special characters or trimming whitespace but it doesn't appear to affect the compared results, so I thought maybe there is an issue between the two databases using different NLS_CHARACTERSETS and the conversion to Strings.

Using `select * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS;` I get that one database uses `NLS_CHARACTERSET,AL32UTF8` while the other uses `NLS_CHARACTERSET,WE8MSWIN1252`.

Is it possible to standardize the output of the text using getString that would take into account the different encodings on the database?  Or is there something else I may be overlooking?

Currently doing this:

```
 List<String> databaseList = new ArrayList<>();
  while (rs.next()) {
    int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

    StringBuilder rsStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++ ){
        String rsString = null;
        try {
            rsString = rs.getString(i);
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        rsStringBuilder.append(rsString).append(",");

    }

    databaseList.add(rsStringBuilder.toString());
  }
```

I would then compare the results of the databaseList from database one with the databaseList from database two.
I've also tried this to standardize the information, but it returns some  characters that don't print correctly, and the differences are still marked incorrectly in the same locations:

```
   for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {

          byte[] bytes = rs.getBytes(i);
          String rsString;
          if (bytes != null) {

            rsString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            rsStringBuilder.append(rsString).append(",");

          } else {

            rsString = "NULLVALUE";
            rsStringBuilder.append(rsString).append(",");
          }

}
```

It gives back something like this `A_C16911,USUMMARY,VARCHAR2,�8,IAMNULL,Y,`.
I thought of trying this after reading some other answers about using UTF-8 as a standard. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost certain that it is due to the database's NLS_CHARACTERSET settings; the Unicode AL32UTF8 character set value for a right single quotation mark `’` is `U+2019`; for WE8MSWIN1252 it is `0x92`.

You may have to bump through a char[] array populated from the [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getChars-int-int-char:A-int-), and for each element, do the following from the Character class: invoke [codePointAt(char[] a, int index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#codePointAt-char:A-int-) call, and then use the returned `int` to call [isAlphabetic(int codePoint)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic-int-), and then maybe [isDigit(int codePoint)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-int-) and then if either of those are true, compare against the other database, and if both are false, you are probably dealing with a punctuation mark or symbol that are different in the two character sets, and can probably be ignored.

To make your comparison more robust, you will also probably want to check [isWhitespace(int codePoint)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-int-) as a common issue I see is when people cut and paste from say a Microsoft Word document or a web page that includes a non-breaking space (`U+00A0`) and the database contains a regular space (`U+0020`). That method also checks for tabs, vertical tabs, etc.